# Is it now safe to use PHP echo short tags?

Tags: php, php-shorttags

Is it now totally and completely safe to use

```
<?=$var ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

Comment: In PHP 5.4 and above. Short tags are always enabled.

Comment: I never knew it to be unsafe.  Can you point me to docs about it?

Comment: Related but, as the OP says, old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Only the short tags with echo `<?= ?>`.

Comment: @halfer I guess he means "safe" from the developers point of view: They cannot break because of some settings, especially when they are the defaults.

Comment: I hate the short tags for no sensible reason at all (must be genetic), even though the only downside I'm aware of has been portability of code to a server which doesn't support them. 5.4 changes that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't use the words "totally" and "completely", but with PHP5.4 the "short-open-and-echo"-syntax is part of the core and thus always available. Remind, that I only talk about `<?= ?>` and not the "regular" short-open-tags `<? ?>`.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. **As of PHP 5.4.0 from 01-Mar-2012 you can use short tag**. From [php 5.4 change log](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php),

> ```
> <?= is now always available regardless of the short_open_tag setting.
> ```

This was a *General improvement*.

So if you have PHP 5.4 you can use `<?=` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is no real issue with using `<?=$var?>`, but if you want to be totally prepared for a host that doesn't have this enabled, then you may want to write it using full statement.

Typically, you can enable this feature even if it's disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to always use the regular `<?php` tag. That way you are sure that your scripts are always compatible with any PHP installation, regardless of the PHP version or php.ini settings.

Even more important if you are developing code that's meant to be shared, such as a library.

Answer (score 0):

ref: http://php.net/ChangeLog.php#5.4.32

"short open tag  is now always available regardless of the short_open_tagsetting"

Answer (score -2):

Yes. As of PHP 5.4, echo tags are always enabled unless your host disables them.

Comment: Nope, thats not possible anymore.